# React contenteditable in stateless component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, contenteditable

I am trying to implement a contenteditable div inside a stateless react component.

I keep getting the below warning:

```
warning.js:36 Warning: A component is `contentEditable` and contains `children` managed by React. It is now your responsibility to guarantee that none of those nodes are unexpectedly modified or duplicated. This is probably not intentional.
```

How do I fix this?

Also how do I read contents of div on change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As with any React application, browser plugins and extensions that modify 
>   the DOM can cause Draft editors to break.
>
> Grammar checkers, for instance, may modify the DOM within
>   contentEditable elements, adding styles like underlines and
>   backgrounds. Since React cannot reconcile the DOM if the browser does
>   not match its expectations, the editor state may fail to remain in
>   sync with the DOM.

https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/issues/53

A known error. As for reading whats in a div, assign the element an id and..

```
oDoc = document.getElementById("divelement");
sDefTxt = oDoc.innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 18):

Add `suppressContentEditableWarning="true"` to contenteditable div.

Reference: https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/issues/81

Comment: Adding `="true"` is not necessary as any props without value is automatically coerced to `true` as their value.

Answer (score 2):

```js
Warning: A component is `contentEditable` and contains `children` managed by React
```

Resolved by adding...

```js
//...
<div 
   suppressContentEditableWarning={true} // <-- Add this
   className="MyClass"
   onClick={ ()=> { onEidtHandler() } }
   onBlur={ ()=> { onSaveHandler() }
  >
    Editable content
</div>
//...
```

Comment: Adding `={true}` is not necessary as any props without value is automatically coerced to `true` as their value.